# How to access variables and entity attributes in amazon Sumerian

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-sumerian

I need help with a few things with Amazon Sumerian:

- How can I access an entity's attribute in a script?
- How can I access a variable from another script?

This is the code I tried to access an entity's variable that I set in the state machine but it returns undefined.

```
    function setup(args, ctx) {
       ctx.runButton = ctx.world.by.name('RunButton').first();
       console.log(ctx.runButton.getAttribute('isReset'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the correct method (`<entity>.getAttribute()`), but at the time `setup()` is called your state machine won't have actually been started. Try putting that code in your `update()` method and see if you get a different result.

For you second question, can you explain a bit more about what you mean when you say "access a variable from another script"?